# Shared Authentication and HttpContext Session between WebAPI and MVC running on separate servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC 4.5 application which serves up the website content - I am using it for bundling and routing, pretty basic.

On the checkout page is a multi-step form which uses knockoutjs.

I then have a seperate web service which accepts orders via AJAX from the knockoutjs checkout submission.

The sites run on different servers (https://www.myapp.com and https://api.myapp.com).

The idea was to use a token fetched from the api and used during api communications.

For other parts of the site there is a submission for with a CAPTCHA type field,

From the code [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19013/Creating-and-Using-a-CAPTCHA-in-ASPNET-MVC.htm) a session is used with `context.HttpContext.Session["captchastring"] = randomString;`. Similarly, I would need to store a calculated value for the user's session so I can identify individual checkouts and verify CAPTCHA (and other things) on submission.

As we can't share this context between two different web server processes, I guess we could double dispatch from the MVC web server asking the API to get a session token and then rendering the view with this token built in but this feels clunky.

I have two questions:

1. Am i going about this wrong, or do i bite the bullet and put some
   parts of the app in to the WebAPI within the same MVC application so
   sessions can be shared?
2. What other authentication schemes exist would be useful for the
   above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make another api project which will be used for authentication. so mvc project  and api project will use that third api for authentication.

but since you have token based authentication, that token is saved into db nad I supose that both project use same database so you can easily vlaidate token. Also it is better practice to put toke into request header.